# Can use a different blob storage connection string in my azure function (c#) depending if I am in dev or prod?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I built an azure function that gets an XML file from a POST request, converts it to JSON and uploads it to an azure blob storage container. Currently I just have the connection string to the container hard coded within my function. However the issue is, the file needs to be uploaded to a different container depending whether the dev or prod deployment of the function is being used.

```
var connectionString = "sampleConnectionString";
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    var containerNameXML = "sampleContainerName";
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerNameXML);
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(xmlFileName);
```

I know I can store the connection string in a local.settings.json file and access it in the code, but  that would only be for one of the environments. So I am wondering if it is possible to overwrite the local environment variable via azure for each environment or something similar.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: In azure you can set the config value for each deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change settings in Azure for your functions app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal